# How to test a single image on tensorflow MNIST model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

I,ve followed the tutorial in tensorflow tutorial to build a **MNIST model** for hand written digits recognition. I want to **test the model** by inputing a **single image to the classifier** and get the output it predicted.

Here is the complete code of the classifier.

I've tried by reading the image using imread but it didn't worked

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pylab
import os
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"],[-1,28,28,1])

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[5,5],
        padding = "same",
        activation = tf.nn.relu)

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool1,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=5,
        padding="same",
        activation = tf.nn.relu)

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [ -1, 7 * 7 * 64 ] )

    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate = 0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

    predictions = {
    "classes":tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    "probabilites": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)


    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

    eval_metric_ops={
    "accuracy":tf.metrics.accuracy(
        labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

  # Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")

  Set up logging for predictions
  Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

  # Train the model
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_data},
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=100,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
  mnist_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=20000,
      hooks=[logging_hook])

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": eval_data},
      y=eval_labels,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)
```

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO! I am sure many of us here can answer the question you asked. But this is not the way how this community works. You need to tell us like "I want to do this. This is my code. I am facing this issue with it. Can you help me?". Here we can't ask like "I want to do this. Can you write the code for me?". Tell the community what you have tried & we will help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A resource I found really helpful was Tensorflow's official tutorial, which includes a demo of their Estimator. In it, you can find how to test numpy arrays with the model. Here's the link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/mnist

Hope this helps!